# How to add customFields in salesforce object using jsforce module..? using the metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce

```
// creating metadata
var metadata = {

  fullName: 'SampleObject__c', 
  label: 'Sample Object',
  label: 'Sample Object',
  pluralLabel: 'Sample Object',
  nameField: {
    type: 'Text',
    label: 'Sample Object'
  },
  deploymentStatus: 'Deployed',
  sharingModel: 'ReadWrite'
};

conn.metadata.create('CustomObject', metadata, function(err, results) {
  if (err) { 
    console.err(err); 
  }
  else{
    console.log('success ? : ' + result.success);
    console.log('fullName : ' + result.fullName);
  }
```

});

I'm not able to create a customField here. Only Object is getting created and there is no documentation available to create a custom field using jsforce. I have tried one approach, i.e, after successful creation of the custom object, i have update the metadata with custom fields, but failed. What is the approach to create customFields in the customObject.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I'm currently in the same boat and would love to go on to the next phase of this project. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Add an array of fields to your custom object meta data definition.  I had a hard time with this too.  I figured it out by creating the fields in Salesforce setup->create->objects (point and click admin) and then reading the metadata produced via:

```
conn.metadata.read(type, [fullName1, fullName2, ..], callback)
```

Put the array of objects below into the metadata variable and it should work.

```
fields: [ { fullName: 'A_Value__c',
           externalId: 'false',
                label: 'A Value 2',
           precision: '18',
            required: 'false',
               scale: '0',
       trackTrending: 'false',
                type: 'Number',
              unique: 'false' },
         {  fullName: 'A3_Value__c',
          externalId: 'false',
               label: 'A Value 3',
           precision: '18',
            required: 'false',
               scale: '0',
       trackTrending: 'false',
                type: 'Number',
              unique: 'false' } ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the following error when I tried to create CustomField

```
{
  "errors":
      {"message":"Must specify the name in the CustomObject.CustomField format (e.g. Account.MyNewCustomField), Name:SampleObject__c, Delimiter:.","statusCode":"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION"},
       "fullName":"SampleObject__c",
       "success":false
}
```

Hence the following metadata is passed to create a custom field for Lead object:

```
var metadata = {
  fullName: 'Lead.SampleField__c',
  length: 100, 
  type: 'Text',
  label: 'Sample Field'
};

connection.metadata.create('CustomField', metadata, function(err, result){});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}' });
var metadata = {
    fullName: 'TestObject1__c.SampleField__c',
    length: '75', 
    type: 'Text',
    label: 'Sample Field'
};
connection.metadata.create('CustomField', metadata , function(err, result){
    if (err) { 
        console.error(err); 
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }

});
```

But be sure that you already have Created Test_Object custom object. You can create both custom object and custom fields at the same time too. I have tried it and working fine. and to create custom object do like this :

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}' });
var metadata = [{
    fullName: 'TestObject1__c',
    label: 'Test Object 1',
    pluralLabel: 'Test Object 1',
    nameField: {
        type: 'Text',
        label: 'Test Object Name'
    },
    deploymentStatus: 'Deployed',
    sharingModel: 'ReadWrite'
}];

    conn.metadata.create('CustomObject', metadata, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { 
            console.error(err); 
        }

        for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var result = results[i];
            console.log('success ? : ' + result.success);
            console.log('fullName : ' + result.fullName);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got simple solution. Just do as :

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: '{!$Api.Session_Id}' });

    var metadata = [{
        fullName: 'TestObject1__c',
        label: 'Test Object 1',
        pluralLabel: 'Test Object 1',
        nameField: {
            type: 'Text',
            label: 'Test Object Name'
        },
        filds : {
           "fullName": "devcqe7__Org_test__c",
            "description": "This field records division for training session.",
            "externalId": "false",
            "label": "Org. Division",
            "required": "false",
            "trackTrending": "false",
            "type": "Picklist",
            "valueSet": {
                "restricted": "true",
                "valueSetName": "devcqe7__SQX_Division"
            }
        },
        deploymentStatus: 'Deployed',
        sharingModel: 'ReadWrite'
    }];

    conn.metadata.upsert('CustomObject', metadata, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { 
            console.err(err); 
        }

        for (var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var result = results[i];
            console.log('success ? : ' + result.success);
            console.log('fullName : ' + result.fullName);
        }
    });
```